# Alternatives to std::reverse to reserve all elements in a vector?

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<int> temp;
temp.insert(temp.begin(), points1.begin(), points1.end());
points1.clear();
std::vector<int> points1(temp.end(), temp.begin());
temp.clear();
```

I tried this but I've got an exception connects to memory allocation.

Comment: What exact exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`std::rbegin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) to iterate in the reverse order.

If you try `points1(temp.end(), temp.begin());`, it starts from and illegal iterator (the end...).

Also, you're declaring `points1` a second time in the code you provided

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one line of code. Construct a temporary vector using [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) and then [swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) its contents back into the original vector.

```
// original vector
std::vector<int> points1;

// create temporary using reverse iterators and swap with original vector
std::vector<int>(points1.rbegin(), points1.rend()).swap(points1);

// unnamed temporary is destroyed automatically
```

[Compiler Explorer demo](https://godbolt.org/z/34BR6y)